# node. js error while installing a node module

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules, react-native-maps

[image]

I get the above error while running command

```
npm install react-native-map --save
```

I read a few post on how to solve this, but it did not help:

I tried doing the following

```
rm ./package-lock.json
npm cache clear --force
```

Still same error

Comment: Have just installed the above package, and got installed properly. Can you please for node version. I have installed the same on node version 6.9.4 . May be it will help

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Instead copy and paste the text into the question for better searchability, protection against dead image URLs, and to allow others to easily copy the relevant text.

Comment: It seems handshake error. Are you behind proxy?